# Multi level menu with jquery show and hide divs

Tags: jquery, html

On page load I would like only menu 1 to display. Then when you click projects, menu-2 shows next to it, then click either current or archive, and it displays menu-3.  How do I do this in jQuery simply?

Something along the lines of http://www.davidchipperfield.co.uk (except that is flash)

```
<div class="menu-1">
    <div>Projects</div>
    <div>Services</div>
    <div>Contact</div>
</div>
<div class="menu-2">
    <div>Current</div>
    <div>Archive</div>
</div>
<div class="menu-3">
    <div>Residential</div>
    <div>Retail</div>
    <div>Health</div>
    <div>Commercial</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can achieve it using click function

Comment: Can you point me in the direction ofhow to use this function?

Answer (score 0):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5B2Hg/1)***

Add a class `projects` to the div to make the selector easily selectable.

jQuery

```
$('.projects').click(function(e){
    $('.menu-2').toggle();
});
$('.menu-2').click(function(e) {
    $('.menu-3').toggle();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu-1">
    <div class="projects">Projects</div>
    <div>Services</div>
    <div>Contact</div>
</div>
<div class="menu-2" style="display:none">
    <div>Current</div>
    <div>Archive</div>
</div>
<div class="menu-3" style="display:none">
    <div>Residential</div>
    <div>Retail</div>
    <div>Health</div>
    <div>Commercial</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple way of approaching the problem with some in-line comments to guide you.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VXgsN/2/)

```
// Hide menu 2 and 3 initially
$('.menu-2, .menu-3').hide();

// Look at all the divs inside of the first menu when they're clicked
$('.menu-1 div').click(function(){
    // If the clicked div has a text of Projects, then toggle the second menu
    if($(this).text() === 'Projects'){
        $('.menu-2').toggle();   
    } 
});

// If any div in the second menu is clicked, toggle the third menu.
$('.menu-2 div').click(function(){
    $('.menu-3').toggle();
});
```